# Is it possible to find the seasal index after fitting ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

Is it possible to find the seasonal index after ARIMA model?

My data is the number of visitors daily. I found the seasonal effect on the day of the weeks. Seasonal index was considered from a decomposition method.

Is it correct? My target needs to fit ARIMA model but the seasonal index was calculated from a decomposition method.

However, If you have methods related to the seasonal index after fitting ARIMA model, please tell me.

I need to clarify seasonal index daily.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use a SARMAX model possibly containing 6 indicator series (seasonal factor) . If you wish please post your results and your actual data.